# Running command in c++ and then run a command within that program

Tags: c++, cmd

In c++ is there a way to run a command in a program that has been opened using system(), all this being done programatically.

ie:

open git bash

```
system("start \"\" \"c:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\" --login -i");
```

then within the new opened git bash window cd back two directories

```
"cd ../../"
```

Comment: Theoretically, it completely depends on how your child program is designed, and it is nothing related with C++ language. I have no idea on how does git bash accepts commands, you may refer to its user manual.

Comment: yeah it accepts cd ../../

Comment: Your question is to broad... Yes it is possible. your simple example you can just pass the command you want to be executed as a shell argument with `-c` (if it is a bash). However, this is probalby not what you want... So it depends on your target application... If the application uses stdin then you can redirect the pipe and send strings to the target application. There are libraries for that purpose, e.g. [boost::process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/process.html).

Comment: I just want to open the git bash window and go 2 directories back within it mate, programatically

Comment: do you on windows?

Comment: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13229748/1810087) should `system("start \"\" \"c:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\" --login -i -c ..\\..\\");` should do... (or something similar with -c).

Comment: adding the -c ..\\..\\ just seems to close the window

Comment: No, but it does not do anything else: just open a shell, goes back two directories, closes the shell... what did you expect?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: if I run my code in the question it keeps the git bash window open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume you are on windows, start command can set working path with `/D`

```
start /D "./../.." "c:/Program Files/Git/in/sh.exe" --login -i
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand correctly, but instead of launching just `bash`, why don't you launch from your C++ program a bash script; all the commands in the script will be executed.

```
system("/bin/bash -c myscript.sh");
```

Bash will be launched, but instead of a interactive shell, the commands in the script file `myscript.sh` will be executed.

However, I would use a different approach, rather than `system(...)`. See the `exec*(...)` family of functions, and the `fork()` call.  There are tons of pages where to look, and dozens of questions in this portal, as an example [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1697440/2526978).

Comment: system, exec, fork... all bad advice, as he is most likely on Windows...